# If $M = \partial W$, with $W$ parallelizable, then an embedding $\iota : M \to S^{n+k}$ extends to an embedding $W \to D^{n+k+1}$

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, vector-bundles

Suppose $M$ is an $n$-dimensional $s$-parallelizable manifold which is the boundary of the parallelizable compact manifold $W$. It is claimed in Milnor & Kervaire's Groups of Homotopy Spheres paper that an embedding $\iota : M \to S^{n + k}$ (for $k > n+1$) may be extended to an embedding $W \to D^{n+k+1}$. I can't see why this is true, and they don't give a reference. Can anyone see why this is true, or give a reference?

Comment: Because of the dimension constraints, this is no more than a relative version of the Whitney embedding theorem. You can find a proof in eg Hirsch.

Comment: Can you tell me the page? I've tried looking, and found some similar statements, but not really what I want.

Comment: I don't know the page... the result will be around section 2.1 or 2.2, and strictly speaking, it's something like "If the map on the boundary is an embedding, the set of all extensions that are embeddings is dense in the set of all extensions." If you can't find it I can sketch a proof of a weaker result here later.

Comment: The closest I can seem to find is exercise $4$ in section $3$ of chapter $2$, which states (in particular) that for $q > 2n$, any embedding of $\partial (M^n)$ in $\mathbb{R}^q$ can be extended to an embedding of $M$ (into $\mathbb{R}^q$). This seems close to what I want, and maybe it can be deduced from this. I'll try to think about it.

Comment: The same question has been answered here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/65092/embedding-a-manifold-in-the-disk?rq=1 . If anyone wants to close as duplicate it's fine by me.